# Can i delete a Battle.net account?

Tags: battle.net

I made myself a new Battle.net account. I want to delete the old one because I don't want to have my name on 2 accounts.

How do I delete the old Battle.net account?

Answer (score 3):

You can't automatically delete an account.

You have to contact custom support to request your account to be deactivated.

They'll probably ask you to go through a series of steps to prove authenticity of yourself and your ownership of the account.